# Template changes font code when editing

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, code, edit

I have created a template from different content areas based on free format. The problem I have is that at first all the content is charged on the template but when I want to edit the content of that area the code is modified and the content does not charge well. How can this problem be solved as I need to change the content of each mailing and I need to use the templates.

Comment: Marc, i think you'll need to be a bit more specific to get answers. To start, is this related to standard salesforce templates or to the marketing cloud ?

Comment: Exacttarget, Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 0):

I never use any of the WYSIWYG ContentArea types/formats for this very reason.  My recommendation would be to stick to `HTML Only`.  Even though it's not the easiest to update if you're not comfortable with HTML, you're CSS won't get jacked up by all of the WYSIWYG parsing.

[image: Content Area Types]